# Why am I seeing an empty density plot, despite no errors in the editor log?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

As a learning exercise I decided to try plotting a density plot of continuously-compounded daily returns of the Nasdaq 100 index for calendar year 2020.  I am unable to get vega-lite to produce any visualization, and yet there are no errors in the online editor.  I'm just inexplicably given an empty plot.

[image: empty vega-lite plot]

Because of the embedded data, the plot spec is some 2500 lines long, so I've saved it as a gist:  https://gist.github.com/nathanvy/2c080ee0b7e93b11e544c5275d31f2b1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change logreturn to value:

[image]

```
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "title": "Nasdaq 100 (NDX) Log Returns, 2020",
  "mark": "area",
  "transform": [{"density": "logreturn"}],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "value",
      "title": "Logarithmic Daily Return",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "density",
      "title": "Probability of Return",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was confused by the spec.